# solve this partial integration with step function

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, laplace-transform

I would like to know how to solve this partial integration.
The equation I got is based on the following convolution:

$$t^2e^{-2t} * te^t$$

The part I am having a hard time with is the (t-u) coefficient.

$$\int_0^t ue^{u} (t-u)e^{(t-u)}du$$
$$ = \int_0^t ue^{u} e^t e^{-u} (t-u)du$$
$$ = \int_0^t ue^{-2u} (t-u)e^{t}du$$

I tried turning the convolution the other way around but I think this might result in an even harder integration.

Comment: Don't forget that integration is linear, so you can break your integral into two, if you like.

Comment: I don't see how this would solve my issue here unfortunately.

Comment: Hm, after a second look, your integral looks a bit strange. You have $t$ as integration variable and $t$ as limit. Is that on purpose? Also, in the convolution you write you have a $t^2$ that I don't see anywhere else... Please confirm/change the question accordingly.

Comment: typo, I edited it

Comment: What about the square (and the $-2$ inside the exponential function)? And what about the step function (title)? Where is it? The reason I ask these questions is that it is much better if we help on the correct problems...

Comment: Edited just now

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is tagged Laplace transform, I suspect that the convolution should be
$$
t^2e^{-2t}*te^t=\int_0^t u^2e^{-2u}(t-u)e^{t-u}\,du.
$$
Using linearity (and the fact that the $t$-dependence can go outside the integral), this integral can be written as
$$
te^t\int_0^tu^2e^{-3u}\,du-e^t\int_0^tu^3e^{-3u}\,du.
$$
I suggest that you start to integrate by parts in both integrals (differentiating the polynomial part of course). Tell me if you have a problem doing so.

Comment: Are you sure that you are allowed to put te^t outside? as t is a variable in time domain and is replaced by the variable u in the laplace domain, I would think it should not be placed outside the integral

Comment: Yes, since we integrate with respect to $u$ it is allowed.

Comment: mhm I understand this part. But.. te^t converted in the laplace domain becomes ue^u. So no t's anywhere. And as we integrare with respect to u, this means it is a variable. Or am I wrong?

Comment: I might misunderstand your question, but you are doing a convolution here right? So there is no such thing as Laplace domain involved.

Comment: Yes I started with an equation with initial values. Transformed the equation in the laplace domain. I now have this convolution. By solving this convolution I ll normally get the solution to this equation

Comment: maybe a few steps more would clarify everything

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following way :

Let, $ t-u = p ==> dt = dp $

$\int_{-u}^0 p e^p dp$

Now try  integration by parts.

$\int_{-u}^0 p e^p dp = pe^p|_{-u}^0 - \int_{-u}^0 e^p dp = -e^{-u} - 1+e^{-u}$

The answer is:

$-e^{p-t} - 1+e^{p-t} $

Hope this might help!

Answer (score 0):

You have edited the question:

Ok now you may try the following way :

$\int (tue^{tu}) - \int u^2 e^t$

then use integration by parts for the first part and the second part is easy integration.